# How to disable radio buttons if one is seleced in Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

For example I have an entity field which starts null and will show the radio buttons, within the Admin pages once a radio button has been selected and saved into the entity then those radio buttons need to be 'disabled', still visible but not intractable.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
{
    $form->add('radio_buttons', ChoiceType::class,
    array('choices' => array(
        "choice 1" => 'input1',
        "choice 2" => 'input2'),
        'choices_as_values' => true, 'multiple'=>false, 'expanded'=>true, 'disabled' => false));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can put a condition in your form to check wether a field is already filled or not.
(Assuming the method is named getRadioButton())

```
if ($this->getSubject()->getRadioButton() != null) {
    $form->add(here tell than you need disabled buttons)
} else {
    $form->add(here tell than you need buttons)
}
```

also, in form field, you can add "html" attribute doing this:

```
->add('radio_buttons', ChoiceType::class,array(
    'what you want'=>'ok',
    'attr'=>array("disabled" => true))
```

so finally it'd give something like

```
if ($this->getSubject()->getRadioButton() != null) {
    $form->add('radio_buttons', ChoiceType::class,
    array('choices' => array(
         "choice 1" => 'input1',
         "choice 2" => 'input2'),
         'choices_as_values' => true,
         'multiple'=>false,
         'expanded'=>true,
         'attr' => array('disabled'=>true),
    ));
} else {
     $form->add('radio_buttons', ChoiceType::class,
     array('choices' => array(
         "choice 1" => 'input1',
         "choice 2" => 'input2'),
         'choices_as_values' => true,
         'multiple'=>false,
         'expanded'=>true,
     ));
}
```

For more information:

> https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html

Answer (score 0):

Do it in your view.

Check if one of the choice exists, and implement a different code if it does.

I would also recommand to remove the radio buttons if it exists, and replace with a text. That will prevent some smartass to edit the DOM and change the choice.